# Get next birthday from a list of classes

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to create a script that will show which employee has the closest Birthday. I'm working in C#. My class is set up like this

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
    public string Name;
    public int PayGrade;
    public int ID;
    public DateTime BirthdayDT;
}
```

I then have a csv file that creates a list of employees. I'm able to sort the list, and have figured out how to filter by name. But I'm having difficulties finding what birthday comes next.  All the previous questions I've found are either other languages or work off of List instead of List.

Comment: @Kevin: You can't sort by a boolean and an integer at the same time. That code will not work the way you expect/suggest it will. Additionally: if someone's day of birth is after today, then they haven't been born yet and it will be some time before they will be an employee.

Comment: @Kevin, as Flater said, that code is throwing out an error. Any alternative method we can think of?